# Menu toogle to control display, height, and width

Tags: javascript, html, css

currently learning javascript and encounter a problem.
I made a button for mobile screen that if clicked it can expand the background and display the menu. I encounter problem where only the menu content can be clicked back and forth to display and undisplayed, and the background don't.

My goal is

- When I clicked the menu button, both the background will expand and the menu will be displayed.
- and the background can be toggle on and off by clicking the menu button.

Can anyone help me with this problem ?

```js
document.getElementById("menu_button").addEventListener("click",function()
{
    var open1=document.getElementById("opened_menu");
    var open2=document.getElementById("menu_background");

    open2.style.width = '100%';
    open2.style.height = '100vh';

    if(open1.style.display=="none")
    {
        open1.style.display="block";
    }
    else {
        open1.style.display="none";
    }

})
```

```css
.mobile_background {
  display: block;
  width: 2rem;
  height: 3rem;
  background-color: red;
}

.mobile_menu {
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 2rem;
  padding-left: 2rem;
}

#menu_button {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="mobile_background" id="menu_background">
  <div class="mobile_menu" id="opened_menu">
    <p>menu 1</p>
    <p>menu 2</p>
  </div>

  <button type="button" name="button" id="menu_button">
      <div class="inner_menu">
        <p>MENU</p>
      </div>
  </button>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: ``else`` statement will never be run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I bet this is what you want.

```js
document.getElementById("menu_button").addEventListener("click", function() {
  var open1 = document.getElementById("opened_menu");
  var open2 = document.getElementById("menu_background");

  if (open1.style.display == "none") {
    open1.style.display = "block";
    open2.style.width = '100%';
    open2.style.height = '100vh';
  } else {
    open1.style.display = "none";
    open2.style.width = '0%';
    open2.style.height = '0vh';
  }

})
```

```css
.mobile_background {
  display: block;
  width: 0%;
  height: 0vh;
  background-color: red;
}

.mobile_menu {
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 2rem;
  padding-left: 2rem;
}

#menu_button {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="mobile_background" id="menu_background">
  <div class="mobile_menu" id="opened_menu" style="display: none">
    <p>menu 1</p>
    <p>menu 2</p>
  </div>

  <button type="button" name="button" id="menu_button">
      <div class="inner_menu">
        <p>MENU</p>
      </div>
  </button>
</div>
```